# Creating a text based game in Python. How to check for user-input?

Tags: python, while-loop, user-input, text-based, splat

I am creating a text based game in Python and need help with splat parameters.  I have a function that tests if input is valid, and also allows you to access your inventory.  I have two parameters, one that gets the input prompt, and one that is valid answers to that prompt.  The answers is a splat parameter because you can have multiple answers to the prompt.  Here is that function:

```
def input_checker(prompt, *answers):  

    user_input = raw_input(prompt).lower()

    if user_input == "instructions":
        print
        instructions()

    elif user_input == "i" or user_input == "inventory":
        if len(inventory) == 0:
            print "There is nothing in your inventory."
        else:
            print "Your inventory contains:",  ", ".join(inventory)

    else:
        if user_input in answers:
        return user_input
        else:
            while user_input not in answers:
                user_input = raw_input("I'm sorry.  I did not understand your answer.  Consider rephrasing. " + prompt )
                if user_input in answers:
                    return user_input
                    break
```

I have two lists that contain common answers to questions:

```
yes = ["yes", "y", "yup", "yep"]  
no = ["no", "n", "nope"]
```

If I call the function like this:

```
pizza = input_checker("Do you like pizza? ", yes, no)
```

It will always perform the while loop that asks for the input again, but if I remove the 'yes' or 'no' so there is only answer list, it will work

How do I go about having two arguments?  What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Why about declaring the function like this:

```
def input_checker(prompt, answers):  

#...
```

And pass as many lists of valid replied as a concatenated list instead when you call the function?

```
pizza = input_checker("Do you like pizza? ", yes + no)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are after is the following implementation of `userinput()`:

**Example:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

try:
    input = raw_input
except NameError:
    pass

def userinput(prompt, *valid):
    s = input(prompt).strip().lower()
    while s not in valid:
        s = input(prompt).strip().lower()
    return s
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> userinput("Enter [y]es or [n]o: ", "y", "n")
Enter [y]es or [n]o: a
Enter [y]es or [n]o: foo
Enter [y]es or [n]o: y
'y'
```

@Jorge Torres is right; Your "while loop" would never terminate when passing in two lists as "valid input" when you declared `*answers` or in my example `*valid` because you are trying to check if `user_input` or `s` in my case is a member of a `tuple` containing 2 items (*2 lists*).

In your case `answers` would look like this:

```
answers = (["yes", "y", "yup", "yep"], ["no", "n", "nope"],)
```

To illustrate this point:

```
>>> answers = (["yes", "y", "yup", "yep"], ["no", "n", "nope"],)
>>> "yes" in answers
False
>>> "no" in answers
False
```

Comment: I'm kind of new to Python.  What is this try statement for?

Comment: The ``try/except`` defines ``input`` for Python 2/3 compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

```
def input_checker(prompt, *answers):  
# ...
pizza = input_checker("Do you like pizza? ", yes, no)
```

So `answers` is tuple `(["yes", "y", "yup", "yep"], ["no", "n", "nope"])`.

(If you'd call `input_checker("Do you like pizza? ", yes, no, ["foo", "bar"])` then `answers` will be `(["yes", "y", "yup", "yep"], ["no", "n", "nope"], ["foo, "bar")`)

And expression in loop

```
while user_input not in answers:
```

will return `False` and will never end.
You can change code like this

```
input_checker(prompt, answers):
# ...
pizza = input_checker("Do you like pizza? ", yes + no)
```

Comment: If i make the argument splat, and do the yes + no method, why doesn't it work?  It will work if I take it away.

Comment: You mean if you make `input_checker(prompt, *answers)` with `*` before `answer`? Then all arguments after `prompt` go to tuple `answers`. Even _lists_. In case `input_checker(prompt, yes + no)` `answers` will be _tuple_ with _list_ element in it, i. e. `answers` is _tuple_ `(["yes", "y", "yup", "yep", "no", "n", "nope"])`. In while loop you check if `user_input not in answers`, i. e. if any of `answers` elements is _string_ `user_input`. But `answers` only element is `yes + no` list. It doesn't check if `user_input` in that list, it doesn't go deep.